# Why ImageView is not crossing the relativelayout

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I have a ImageView within a RelativeLayout. RelativeLayout Height is fixed as 50dp and ImageView height is bigger that 50dp. I want my ImageView to cross the RelativeLayout.

I attach a screen that i want to implement.

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="#000000"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/home_menu"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/home_logo_bottom"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

`RelativeLayout` is the Parent and `ImageView` is a child inside it. The rule is, if the child is larger than the parent, the child will be clipped so that only whatever fits the parent is visible. So if the parent's height is 50dp, and the child's height is 100dp, You will only see the 50dp content of the child.

If you want to see (in this case) the full ImageView's content, then change the `layout_height` of the RelativeLayout to `wrap_content`. If you want to accomplish the layout as in the image, don't make the ImageView as a child of the RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Use two relative layouts

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/parentlayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="60dp"
   android:background="#000000">

  <RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:background="#000000">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/home_menu"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>


        </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/home_logo_bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

     </RelativeLayout>
```